# Android App for FB LOGIN Unfortunately Stops

Tags: java, android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I tried to create an Android app with FB login. I followed directions from:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837

Build is successful, but the app unfortunately stops.

My logcat is shown below:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>   Process: com.example.android.logintest, PID: 2434
>                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:746)
>                                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:774)
>                                                                                        at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:823)
>                                                                                        at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:489)
>                                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Main activity is as follows:

```
    package com.example.android.logintest;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
    import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
    import com.facebook.FacebookException;
    import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
    import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
    import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new           FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                info.setText(
                        "User ID: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                + "\n" +
                                "Auth Token: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");

            }
        });

    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: are you got your hashkey in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Recheck steps 4 and 5 in the [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837) you have provided.

Above shown NullPointerException generally comes when you haven't provided applicationId of your app in the AndroidManifest Application meta-data

Also make sure you have added com.facebook.FacebookActivity as another activity in your manifest